# Merge parallels edges

Tags: edges

I'm just starting with modeling so please sorry if my question already was too dumb, but I didn't find a solution yet.

In short, I want to merge 2 edges to be only one. They are in same orientation and direction.

[image]

Comment: so I guess they have a common vertex? Just select it and Ctrl X to dissolve?

Comment: Yeah! That's so obvious now :) Thank you a lot  @moonboots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select their common vertex and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to dissolve.

Comment: I didn't know how to convert the comment in a answer. Thank you again for your help! @moonboots

Comment: And I don't have reputation to vote :/

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I just needed to select the vertex between them and then Dissolve the vertices. Credits to @moonbots

[image]